# add nested html tags inside reactjs app render function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to view my tableau dashboard using Reactjs frontend framework. 
 I am trying to embed HTML code into my Reactjs App but i am unable to figure it out.

```
function App() {

  return(
    <div className="App">
        <h1>
           Dashboard
        </h1>

    <script type='text/javascript'>  

--- ----- ----------- --------- --------- --------- -------- -------- -------- -----        
        var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1677637128726');                    
        var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    
        if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { 
            vizElement.style.width='1400px';vizElement.style.height='1727px';
        } else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { 
            vizElement.style.width='1400px';vizElement.style.height='1727px';
        } else { 
            vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1827px';
        }                     
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
        scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    
        vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);
--- -------- ------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------            
    </script>
           </div>
  );
}
```

In the above code how do i add HTML tags inside the App function. As you can see in the end, the code between the dotted lines, i am not able to add those lines inside the tags.
How can i add the below lines between the  tags??

```
var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1677637128726');                    
        var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    
        if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 800 ) { 
            vizElement.style.width='1400px';vizElement.style.height='1727px';
        } else if ( divElement.offsetWidth > 500 ) { 
            vizElement.style.width='1400px';vizElement.style.height='1727px';
        } else { 
            vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height='1827px';
        }                     
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
        scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/
```

Comment: Use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to refer to specific elements and move your other code to an effect hook.

Comment: could you be more specific?